# Resource Booking Calendar for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Just wondering what the recommended way to create a resource booking type app/calendar/list is for Sharepoint 2013. There was an app in the store that has since had a giant price rise and I am unable to use it.

Comment: I'm working on an Office365 (Wave 15) App version of my resource booking codeplex project http://spresourcebooking.codeplex.com.  If you're interested I can let you know when I've completed it ?

Comment: Ian that would be fantastic. What is your expected date for completion?

Comment: I've got a first draft version of working now.  It has an app part and a default page.  I can send you a copy of the .app file to try if you let me know your email address.

Comment: This is complete and tested now.  It's a SharePoint Hosted App so will work with both Office365 and SharePoint 2013.